# After removing some rows in this data frame all information turns NA, what's wrong?

Tags: r

I'm working on a replication of the study for this particular data that you could find in this [link](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?id=53035), the data is named `AProrok_AJPS.tab`, please click on **Download** and then you can choose the RData format.

I want to remove all the rows whose value in a specific column is 1, so with this code:

> df <- data[data$unknownleader!=1,]

After that, however, all the data becomes NA, it becomes all blank basically. I tried to change the type of data between integer, factor, class, etc. but all resulted into the same problem. I am not sure what is with this data file that causes this problem. Could anyone please investigate and show me a possible way to fix it?

Comment: @ErdemAkkas Hi thanks but it's != for different from, the double equal signs == is for equality.

Comment: After loading the data, it seems that all the values for `unknownleader != 1` are in fact `NA`. So that R gives this answer is to be suspected.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Yes, but after running that code, all information in all other entries becomes NA, everything. Should I replace the NA in that `unknownleader` column by 0's first?

Comment: Indexing with NA probably causes your issues here. See this post for some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822426/r-dealing-with-true-false-na-and-nan.

Comment: Try `df <- data[which(data$unknownleader != 1), ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to @PaulHiemstra for pointing out that the problem arose from the NA in the dataset. Then, based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe), I could come up with a solution:

First replacing all the NA in that particular `unknownleader` column to 0:

> df$unknownleader <- replace(df$unknownleader, is.na(df$unknownleader), 0)

Then proceed to remove the rows as mentioned in the question as normally:

> df <- df[df$unknownleader==0, ]

Note that since the `unknownleader` variable happens to be binomial, therefore it still makes sense to replace NA to 0. For other dataset some appropriate adjustments might be needed.