# How to compare to NA when iterating over multiple variables

Tags: r, function, data.table, apply, na

I'm going to give a lot of background (on which I welcome suggestions to improve) that isn't strictly necessary, so you can scroll to the end if you just want to see my main question.

### Background

I have a dataset where I'd like to fill in missing values for several variables according to a few rules. Some example data:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

dt <- data.frame(id = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
                        'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                 var1 = c(1, 1, NA, 1, NA,
                          NA, 5, 5, NA, 5),
                 var2 = c('hi', 'hi', NA, 'hi', 'hi',
                          'bye', NA, 'bye', 'bye', NA),
                 year = c(2005:2009,
                          1995:1998, 2002))
```

Note that the real data is big: 10s of millions of observations, at least 30-40 variables, and I'll be filling in around 10 columns or so, hence the `data.table` approach.

I currently fill them in using a function that finds leads and lags and checks my conditions, like so:

```
fill.in <- function(var, yr, finyr) {
  leadv <- lead(var, order_by = yr)
  lagv <- lag(var, order_by = yr)
  
  leadyr <- lead(yr, order_by = yr)
  lagyr <- lag(yr, order_by = yr)
  
  # ------- build the updated var w/ sequential conditions
  # keep the var as it is if not missing
  try1 <- ifelse(test = !is.na(var),
                 yes = var,
                 no = NA)
  
  # fill in if the lead and lag match and no more than 2 missing years
  try2 <- ifelse(test = is.na(try1) & leadv == lagv &
                        abs(leadyr-lagyr) <= 3 &
                        !is.na(leadv),
                 yes = leadv,
                 no = try1)
  
  # fill in with the lag if it's the final year of observed data
  ifelse(test = is.na(try2) & yr == finyr &
                abs(yr-lagyr) <= 3 & !is.na(lagv),
         yes = lagv,
         no = try2)
}
```

I call this using `data.table`'s `.SD`:

```
setDT(dt)

dt[, finalyr := max(year), by = id]

# variables to iterate over and the new column names
fill.in.vs <- c('var1', 'var2')
fixed.vnames <- paste0('fixed.', fill.in.vs)

# I don't want factor values, so make strings characters
dt$var2 <- as.character(dt$var2)

dt[, (fixed.vnames) := sapply(.SD,
                              FUN = fill.in,
                              yr = year,
                              finyr = finalyr,
                              simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE),
   by = id, .SDcols = fill.in.vs]
```

This gives me the data I want:

```
    id var1 var2 year finalyr fixed.var1 fixed.var2
 1:  a    1   hi 2005    2009          1         hi
 2:  a    1   hi 2006    2009          1         hi
 3:  a   NA <NA> 2007    2009          1         hi
 4:  a    1   hi 2008    2009          1         hi
 5:  a   NA   hi 2009    2009          1         hi
 6:  b   NA  bye 1995    2002         NA        bye
 7:  b    5 <NA> 1996    2002          5        bye
 8:  b    5  bye 1997    2002          5        bye
 9:  b   NA  bye 1998    2002         NA        bye
10:  b    5 <NA> 2002    2002          5       <NA>
```

### Main question

Ok now to my actual question: I want an indicator of rows that have been updated. I don't think the way I'm updating, with `data.table` and `.SD`, allows for making paired variables (by which I mean producing two or three different variables In each iteration), so I thought I would just flag the observations where essentially `original.var != fixed.var`.

This runs into issues because R doesn't like comparing values to `NA`s. (See [here for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822426/dealing-with-true-false-na-and-nan))

I've tried to implement some solutions for this but I keep running into issues with trying to do this over a list of variables. For example, the following works to identify which are the same or not:

```
# this works:
dt$updated.var1 <- mapply(identical, dt$var1, dt$fixed.var1,
                          SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

dt[,c('var1', 'fixed.var1', 'updated.var1')]
    var1 fixed.var1 updated.var1
 1:    1          1         TRUE
 2:    1          1         TRUE
 3:   NA          1        FALSE
 4:    1          1         TRUE
 5:   NA          1        FALSE
 6:   NA         NA         TRUE
 7:    5          5         TRUE
 8:    5          5         TRUE
 9:   NA         NA         TRUE
10:    5          5         TRUE
```

But when I try to use it with `data.table` and lists of variables it returns all `FALSE` for both variables:

```
# indicate updated observations
update.names <- paste0('updated.', fill.in.vs)

# this doesn't work how I want it to:
dt[, (update.names) := mapply(identical,
                              .SD,
                              fixed.vnames,
                              SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE),
   .SDcols = fill.in.vs]

dt[,c('var1', 'fixed.var1', 'updated.var1')]
    var1 fixed.var1 updated.var1
 1:    1          1        FALSE
 2:    1          1        FALSE
 3:   NA          1        FALSE
 4:    1          1        FALSE
 5:   NA          1        FALSE
 6:   NA         NA        FALSE
 7:    5          5        FALSE
 8:    5          5        FALSE
 9:   NA         NA        FALSE
10:    5          5        FALSE
```

I'm not certain what the issue is, but I'm guessing it has to do with my attempt to get `mapply` to recognize the list of the "fixed" variables as variables to iterate over.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am stuck in the background step. When I run `dt[, (fixed.vnames) := sapply(.SD,....)]`, I get `Error: Invalid type returned by vec_proxy_compare().`Can you recheck if the code works for you?

Comment: Sorry about that -- I had a typo in the function. It should work now.

Comment: Sorry if this is naive--if the root problem is how R handles `NA` values when checking (in)equality, have you considered using another value not found in the data (e.g. `999`) as a proxy for `NA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom function to handle this and use `Map` to apply the function for each pair.

```
library(data.table)

new_cols <- function(x, y) {
  z <- x != y | is.na(x) & is.na(y)
  z[is.na(z)] <- TRUE
  z
}

update.names <- paste0('updated.', fill.in.vs)

dt[, (update.names) := Map(new_cols, dt[, ..fixed.vnames], dt[, ..fill.in.vs])]
dt

#    id var1 var2 year finalyr fixed.var1 fixed.var2 updated.var1 updated.var2
# 1:  a    1   hi 2005    2009          1         hi        FALSE        FALSE
# 2:  a    1   hi 2006    2009          1         hi        FALSE        FALSE
# 3:  a   NA <NA> 2007    2009          1         hi         TRUE         TRUE
# 4:  a    1   hi 2008    2009          1         hi        FALSE        FALSE
# 5:  a   NA   hi 2009    2009          1         hi         TRUE        FALSE
# 6:  b   NA  bye 1995    2002         NA        bye         TRUE        FALSE
# 7:  b    5 <NA> 1996    2002          5        bye        FALSE         TRUE
# 8:  b    5  bye 1997    2002          5        bye        FALSE        FALSE
# 9:  b   NA  bye 1998    2002         NA        bye         TRUE        FALSE
#10:  b    5 <NA> 2002    2002          5       <NA>        FALSE         TRUE
```

You might get warnings in the console, please ignore them for now. There is an open issue regarding it. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2988